# ¿Como puedo obtener datos especificos de una tabla intermedia (many to many) en laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy intentando obtener los datos que pertenezcan a un objeto query especifico dentro de una tabla intermedia (many to many) llamada query_question que esta enlazada entre los modelos query - question.
Esta es la relacion que se encuentra en el modelo query.

```
public function getQuestions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class)->withPivot('sub_test_id', 'test_id', 'score', 'answer');
    }
```

Esta es la relacion que se encuentra en el modelo question

```
public function getQueries(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Query::class)->withPivot('sub_test_id', 'test_id', 'score', 'answer');
    }
```

Este es mi esquema de la migracion muchos a muchos

```
Schema::create('query_question', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->bigInteger('question_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('query_id')->unsigned();

            $table->bigInteger('sub_test_id')->unsigned();
            $table->bigInteger('test_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('query_id')->references('id')->on('queries')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade'); 

            $table->foreign('sub_test_id')->references('id')->on('sub_tests')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->foreign('test_id')->references('id')->on('tests')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
                ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->unique(['question_id', 'query_id']);
            $table->double('score');
            $table->string('answer');
        });
```

Aqui estoy intentado obtener los datos que pertenecen a un objeto del modelo query para guardar todos los datos relacionados con el objeto query a un arreglo, pero siempre obtengo null.

```
$answers = array();
        foreach ($query->getQuestions as $answer) {
            array_push($answers, $answer->pivot);   
        }
```

Por ejemplo quiero obtener solamente los que tengan query_id 1 y guardarlos en el arreglo.
Aqui se observa los datos de la tabla intermedia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La verdad veo todo bien, ya te aseguraste que si tengas datos en la BD en la tabla **query_question**?

Algo que puedes hacer antes del foreach es revisar si vienen los datos:
puedes hacer una precarga de las questions e imprimirla con un dd para ver si las trae, y adicional a eso cambiaria los nombres de las relaciones getQuestions  y getQueries a solamente "questions" y "queries"

```
$query= Query::with('questions')->get();
dd(query);
```